# Receiving data on an application server?

Tags: java, sockets, application-server

If I make a socket connection from an application that is running on an application server, where does the returned data go? Is it necessary to create a receiving server socket in the application with a specified port, or is it received on the port at which the server is using to connect to the application and I just need to write something that will extract that data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to read from a socket. You are making socket connection to port 8080 in server. You don't have to worry about the OS -> Server port.

```
public static void readSocket() throws IOException {
    try (Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(new URL("Some Address").getHost()), 8080); 
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The socket is one end-point of two-way communication link between server and client programs of the network.

1. The returned data is sending to your client Socket object, lets call it `clientSocket`. You need to call `clientSocket.getInputStream()` to decode it.
2. No, you dont need to create a receiving server socket in the application. Your client program establishes a connection to the server on your given host and port. `clientSocket` can both send data to server and receive data from server.

For example the client side code:

```
private PrintWriter out = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;

public void listenSocket(){
//Create socket connection
   try{
     clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

     // use out object to send data to server applicaiton
     out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), 
                 true);

     // uses in object to receive data from server application
     in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     System.out.println("Unknown host:" + HOST);
     System.exit(1);
   } catch  (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("No I/O");
     System.exit(1);
   }
}
```